# What would be the negative implications of this improvement of the python language?

Tags: python, syntax

As a Python programmer and algorithmic engineer, I often found the following feature would greatly help to make the code clearer and simpler:

Consider the "break" statement. It happens currently that you have to run a loop inside another loop, or even more embedded loops. Quite often, you have a condition inside the innermost loop that, if fulfilled, should break a more outer loop (I mean, not the loop containing the condition).
This is possible only by using flags, and makes the code heavier and uselessly complicated.

So, I am wondering about what would be the implication of allowing the following syntax:

**break 0** - break the outermost loop

**break 1** - break the next to the outermost loop

**break 2** - break the next to the next to the outermost loop

**etc.** and

**break -1** -  (equivalent to "break") break the loop containing this statement

**break -2** - break the loop just outer to the loop containing this statement

**break -3** - break the loop just outer to the loop just outer the loop containing this statement

**etc.**

For consistency, the same could be do with keyword *continue*, but I have seldom found any need to that.

Comment: What's the real issue with `goto label`?

Comment: there is a goto in python?

Comment: This has been proposed and rejected. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3136/#rejection-notice

Comment: Direct link to the rejection message by GvR with his reasons to reject it: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-July/008663.html

Comment: Looks at this but scroll past the first example which is more the look of Perl https://www.edureka.co/blog/goto-statement-in-python/

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to handle breaking out of multiple levels of nested loops that is not too cumbersome if you're not nested too deep (in which case you really should simplify your code structure instead):

```
while condition1:
   ...
   while condition2:
       ...
       if breakingCondition: break
       ...
   else: pass; break                 # this will break the outer loop
   ...                               # on the inner bearkingCondition
```

*Of course, when you get to 3 levels or more, this may not be sufficient, especially if you want to target a specific nesting level to break out to.  But then the control flow of the code becomes quite hard to follow and specialized flag variables with meaningful names would be in order.*

Comment: Despite that does not solve the problem as I wish, I found that interesting. I was ignorant of the "else" clause for "while". thx.